# Where security role is used

Tags: security, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created a form for a specific group of users in my CRM 2011 system. I want only them to be able to see this form. I can copy their a security role and set the form for this security role only, but I will have a a problem:

they are currently in a security role with another group of users. If I copy the security role, the will not longer see the specific customization's all over across the system.

I only want one form to be different from the others. Is there any way I can find all the forms that are enabled for the specific security role (in order to give the new role this rights too)?

Comment: I'm not sure how CRM handles it, but I know that users can be assigned to multiple roles. I believe (though I could be wrong) that for each field, it takes the highest value from their roles. So you should be able to make a new one that just enables that form and add it to those users

Comment: @DanDrews I can't see any Priority field or UP/DOWN Button. How could I order the security roles? (For my users to see a specific form as first form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions based on your question: You already have default form for the entity that is used by all users (All Users). You want to add an additional form to that entity that is only available to some of the users (Select Users). All Users are currently assigned a security role that gives them the necessary access to the system.

1. Create a new security role (Form Specific Role). You don't have to give this role any privileges just a name.
2. Assign the *Select Users* the *Form Specific Role*. Do **NOT** remove their other security role(s).
3. Add the new form the entity, **Restricted Form**.
4. Highlight the new form and click ***Enable Security Roles***. Select the option *Display only to these selected security roles* and select the *Form Specific Role* you created in step # 1. Make sure ***Enabled for fallback*** is *unchecked*. Click *Ok*.
   [image]
5. From the forms list ***Form Order*** and select ***Main Form Set*** (or the appropriate form type if you are working on a Mobile or Quick Create Form.

   [image]
6. Use the Up/Down arrows to make the new, **Restricted Form**, the top choice.
   [image]
7. Save and Publish all changes.

Now whenever a user that has been assigned the security role accesses this entity their default form choice will be the Restricted Form. There will be **NO** impact to any other forms they are accessing or any of their privileges in the rest of the system, as required by your problem statement.

Comment: Great answer, but I need to remove the other security role.

Comment: If you need to remove it then remove it. I'm not sure what that has to do with giving them access to a specific form.

Comment: Thats what I will do. but Since I need remove the old role, need to check all the forms manually.